# Using AMD Graphics Card 16.04LTS

Tags: lenovo

Hello I am newish to Desktop Linux. I have gone with Kubuntu. I am having some problems with getting my dedicated graphics card to work.

I have recently installed KUbuntu 16.04 LTS on my Lenovo Z51-70. It has both integrated Intel HD5500 graphics and AMD Radeon R9 M375 graphics card.

When I run the command "sudo lshw -c video", it is only showing the Intel graphics card. How can I install or switch to AMD graphics?

Output of `sudo lshw -c video` is:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't, at least not right now.

Explanation:

When Ubuntu runs into a switchable graphics situation, it will use the integrated graphics by default and keep doing so until a proprietary driver is installed for the discrete graphics.

Now, you may be thinking, "great, I can just install the proprietary drivers for my AMD card." Well, unfortunately, you can't. Up until 16.04, AMD provided a proprietary graphics driver for Linux known as `fglrx`. This worked nicely (for the cards that were supported, but that's a different issue) until AMD decided it would not be supporting its Linux driver anymore.

Unsupported doesn't necessarily mean incompatible. There was the possibility of `fglrx` working on 16.04, but it's been shown that `fglrx` does *not* work with 16.04. Users on 16.04 are currently stuck with generic drivers for their AMD card, forcing them to use integrated graphics if they have that setup.

I believe there is a new proprietary driver in the making, but it's very buggy and not worth attempting to install just yet. For now, if you need the performance from your discrete card, you will have to downgrade to 15.10 or 14.04 (if you want LTS).

Answer (score 0):

The latest kernel 4.17 has extended support for various AMD graphics card. So, I guess, now you can use AMD card instead of inbuild intel card.

Comment: Hi Saurav and welcome to askubuntu! To install the latest kernel can be challenging and dangerous, since it may become unstable. Since the question poster is a newish, I would not install this kernel unless it is unavoidable.